# how do I pass variables to angularjs factories

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass some variables to a angular factory which will then loop the data.

Here's what I have

the factory:

```
factory.startLoop = function(filter, attribute){
    var uniqueTypes = [];
    for(i = 0; i< filter.length; i++){    
        if(uniqueTypes.indexOf(filter[i].attribute) === -1){
            uniqueTypes.push(filter[i].attribute);

        }        
    }

var input = uniqueTypes;
```

the controller

```
var category = 'category';
output = loopFactory.startLoop(firstPointFiveFilter, category);
```

But when I run this I undefined on the input variable.

if I remove the attribute and simply do `filter[i].category` then it works.

So the problem is the attribute variable.

Comment: It was as simple as that, I will elaborate the question next time!

Thanks alot!

Do you want to post the answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to filter's property using dot notation.
Instead of `filter[i].attribute`, you need to use `filter[i][attribute]`.